# Invalid runtime for JavaSE-1.8: The path points to a missing or inaccessible folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

Earlier  vscode was working normally but now it can't recognize the paths for runtime.

Environment:

VSCode Version: 1.77.1 (user setup)

OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621

Java Extension Version: v0.49.1

JDK Version:  "11.0.15" 2022-04-19

I'm getting 2 errors

"Invalid runtime for JavaSE-1.8: The path points to a missing or inaccessible folder
(C:\Users\tj675\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\pleiades.java-extension-pack-jdk\8)."

and

"Invalid runtime for JavaSE-19: The path points to a missing or inaccessible folder (C:\Users\tj675\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\pleiades.java-extension-pack-jdk\19)."

```
 {
        "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
        "path": "C:\\Users\\tj675\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\globalStorage\\pleiades.java-extension-pack-jdk\\8"
    },
    
    {
        "name": "JavaSE-11",
        "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Eclipse Adoptium\\jdk-11.0.15.10-hotspot"
    },
    {
        "name": "JavaSE-17",
        "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-17.0.5",
        "default": true
    },
    
    
    {
        "name": "JavaSE-19",
       "path": "C:\\Users\\tj675\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\globalStorage\\pleiades.java-extension-pack-jdk\\19"
    }
```

Comment: _exact_ error message as text please. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check that the following folders exist and that you have access rights to them.

C:\Users\tj675\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\pleiades.java-extension-pack-jdk\8
C:\Users\tj675\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\pleiades.java-extension-pack-jdk\19